# Illegal access error when initializing SparkConf - MLLIB

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Team,

I'm just playing around with spark and mllib. Installed scala and spark, versions mentioned below.

Scala - 2.11.7
Spark - 1.4.0 (Did an mvn package with -Dscala-2.11)

I'm trying to run the Java classification, clustering examples that came along with the documentation. However, I'm getting the illegal access error when I'm trying to initialize the SparkConf object.

I'm trying to do something as basic as this :

```
> SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SVM Classifier Example");
> SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
```

Please find the error trace below :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to
>   access method scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.()V from class
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.(Utils.scala:195)  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.(Utils.scala)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkConf.(SparkConf.scala:58)     at
>   MultinomialLogisticRegressionExample.main(MultinomialLogisticRegressionExample.java:15)

How do I go about this? Did some googling and couldn't conclude. Please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try scala 2.10  instead.  I am using mllib and had issues with scala 2.11 After switching to 2.10 it works without problem.